# jquery.datatable only seeing one row with zero configuration

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datatable

Im having a problem with the simple configuration of jquery.datatable.

Im trying to use it with the HTML table. The table is in my view and everything is beeing set in the footer(im using codeigniter).

When im trying to sort on a row it only sorts one row. The first row of the database.

How is this possible and what could i do to fix it.

im calling it in this way

```
        $("#datatable").dataTable();
```

And im trying to use it on this element

```
 <table class="table no-border hover" id="datatable" >
                    <thead>

                    <th colspan="2"></th>
                    <th>Naam</th>
                    <th>Email </th>
                    <th>Feedback</th>
                    <th>Acties</th>
                    </thead>
                    <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
                    <tbody class="no-border-y">
                    <tr class="gradeA">
                        <td class="profile-pic text-center"><span class=""><?php echo form_checkbox() ?></span></td><td><span><?php echo img($imgfolder.$user['profile_pic']); ?></span></td>
                        <td><?php echo $user['last_name'].', '.$user['first_name'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo '<a href="mailto:'.$user['email'].'">'.$user['email'].'</a>' ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <?php
                            echo anchor(
                                $current_class.'/message/create/'.$user['id'], '<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>' ,array(
                                    'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-flat',
                                ) );
                            ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php
                            echo anchor(
                                $current_class.'/view/'.$user['id'], '<i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i>' ,array(
                                    'class' => 'btn btn-info btn-flat',
                                ) );
                            ?>
                            <?php
                            echo anchor(
                                $current_class.'/delete/'.$user['id'], '<i class="fa fa-xing"></i>' ,array(
                                    'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-flat',
                                ));
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your markup is invalid.  Look at your loop structure:

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
<tbody class="no-border-y">
<tr class="gradeA">
<!-- other markup -->
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</tbody>
```

The loop is going to output multiple opening `tbody` tags, the resulting behavior of which is undefined.  Move that to outside the loop so that you're only outputting multiple `tr` elements:

```
<tbody class="no-border-y">
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
<tr class="gradeA">
<!-- other markup -->
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: @BartKlaster: The browser's DOM inspection tools may even have tried to make sense of it for you, making the debugging a little more difficult.  The raw page source would show the error, though.